# FloatingActionButton в Fragment

Tags: java, android, вконтакте, menu

Как можно реализовать такую FloatingActionButton в Fragment, что бы по нажатию на неё всплывало контекстное меню в той же позиции, что и кнопка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ловите событие нажатия  и отображайте popupMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [конструкторах PopupMenu второй параметр](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View)) - вьюха, рядом с которой меню нужно отобразить. Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
    // TODO setOnDismissListener(), setOnMenuItemClickListener()
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
    popupMenu.show();
}
```